# How can I turn this exceptional error message into my custom message in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am writing the script which should validate the user in the active directory and gets some AD information. I am struggling with the error handling in this script:

```
$user = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter your network id').ToUpper()
#check if the user exists in the AD database
$userid= Get-ADUser $user | Select SamAccountName
$userid = $user

 if (($user -match $userid))  {

 Write-Host $user "exists in AD"
 }else{
 write-host "user cannot be found"
 }
```

If someone who uses the script will put incorrect userId (which doesn't exist  in AD), the script will throw an error message :

```
Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'DUMMY' under: 'DC=company,DC=com'.
At line:9 char:11
+ $memoid = Get-ADUser $user | Select SamAccountName
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (DUMMY:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], ADIdentityNotF 
   oundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management. 
   ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Even though incorrect userID was entered, I receive

= DUMMY exists in AD

How can I turn this exceptional error message into my custom message - "The user doesn't exist in AD"? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, it is better not to use the `-Identity` parameter (which you imply in your code by using `Get-ADUser $user`)

Try

```
$userID = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter your network id'

# check if the user exists in the AD database
# this will either return an ADUser object or $null
$user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$userID'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if ($user) {
    Write-Host "$($user.SamAccountName) exists in AD" -ForegroundColor Green
}
else{
    Write-Host "user $($user.SamAccountName) cannot be found" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the exceptions using `try/catch`
In the error message, it is telling that "cannot find that object"
So, your first approach is to check whether the user exists or not in the `If` statement and then put them in `try/catch` like below

```
try{

        $user = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter your network id').ToUpper()
        #check if the user exists in the AD database
        $userid= Get-ADUser $user | Select SamAccountName
        $userid = $user

         if (($user -match $userid))  {

         Write-Host $user "exists in AD"
         }else{
         write-host "user cannot be found"
         }

}
catch
{
    #Your Custom Message in case of the error is coming in Std Out . $_.Exception.Message will catch the exact error message. 
    "Error Message: "+ "$_.Exception.Message"

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your all answers were helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The statement: $userid = $user needs to be deleted. As is it insures that you always have a match.

Next place your call to Get-ADUser in a Try/Catch construct to catch the error.

```
$user = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter your network id').ToUpper()

#check if the user exists in the AD database

Try {
      $userid= Get-ADUser $user -EA "STOP" | Select SamAccountName
      Write-Host $user "exists in AD"
}
Catch {
#*** Process errors here ***
 write-host "user cannot be found"
 Exit
}

#Continue your script here
```

Note: I don't have access to a Server so this is untested but should work in theory!
HTH